# git rebase causes feature branch to lose tracking information

Tags: git, github

Whenever I'm rebasing in my feature branch from our 'master' branch, my feature branch seems to lose its tracking information. What's wrong with this workflow?

```
$ git clone repo_url
$ git co -b feature/my_work_task
```

Do a bunch of work here

```
$ git commit -am"Commit my work"
$ git push # push the branch upstream
$ git checkout master
$ git pull # get whatever changes that have been put into master
$ git co feature/my_work_task
$ git rebase master # everything seems to be good
```

Make some additional changes in my feature branch.

```
$ git commit -am"more changes to update"
$ git push # pushing this to my remote repo
```

The push to the remote repo fails with the following error:

```
To git@github.com:/username/my-repo.git
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> feature/my_work_task (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:/username/my-repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'll do a 'git pull' as suggested which then leads to:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream feature/my_work_task origin/<branch>
```

If I set the upstream information, followed by another attempt to 'git pull', I'll now have all sorts of file conflicts.

What's the best way to have a feature branch that keeps up with the changes from master?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you push a branch you can't rebase it.

Rebase 'replays' all your changes over the master branch (`git rebase master`). This re-writes your index. So, even though your local changes are all preserved and replayed over master (all the various commits regardless of how many times you've rebased) as soon you push the remote server sees a different index and thus your error.

So, once you push your branch you can't rebase master.

Instead:

- `git checkout -b b`
- `git commit -am "stuff"`
- `git push origin b`
- `git checkout master`
- `git pull origin master`
- `git checkout b`
- `git` **merge** `master`

Comment: Oh I see. Now, if I want to finally flatten all of the feature branch changes into master and push it up to master, can I do: git merge --squash feature/branch_name?

Comment: Yep - if you look at your branch's commit references before/after the rebase, you'll see that they completely change.  The commit reference is effectively a hash of the entire state of the repository at that point in time, so even something simple like changing the commit message of a commit will change the commit refs.   When you merge from master into you branch you're adding a new commit on top rather than rewriting history.

Comment: He could `git rebase master` as long as no one else is using the branch.  He just needs to force push that branch.  You do really need to understand what you're doing though.  And, you need to make sure that someone else isn't using the branch, or if they are that they know to rebase as well.  But if the branch is effectively private, there's no harm in force pushing the branch.

Comment: true. but that is really bad habit to get into. Also you're fighting the framework at this point, which is not good either.

Comment: No one else is using the branch (at the moment) but it's possible others will. I'd love to establish a good workflow so all changes from master are periodically folded into the branch and at the end, changes from branch can be merged into master.

Comment: don't rebase after pushing :) merging is a much better habit to get into.